# navigation links with horizontal scrolling

Tags: javascript, gsap, scrolltrigger

https://codepen.io/dev33-developer33/pen/GRwKQzj

I need the menu to be active after scrolling; now it only works when you do a click

I tried this but it doesn't work, something is missing.

```
const navbarLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".navbar a");

function setActive(link) {
  navbarLinks.forEach(el => el.classList.remove("active"));
  link.classList.add("active");
}

navbarLinks.forEach(a => {
  let element = document.querySelector(a.getAttribute("href"));
  ScrollTrigger.create({
    trigger: element,
    start: "top top",
    end: "top bottom",
    onToggle: self => self.isActive && setActive(a)
  });
});
```

Comment: Please update the snippet I made you to make it a [mcve]

Comment: You want the link to become active when you scroll the page to the relevant section? I cannot scroll the sections at all

Comment: yes, this is a horizontal scroll, please scroll

Comment: I cannot scroll. The code does not allow me to scrolll in any way on Chrome

Comment: You might want to have a look at this approach and see if you can change yours to match - it loops through the sections to set up the scrolltrigger so you know the section it's scrolled to: https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/rNrWrXN

Comment: https://codepen.io/dev33-developer33/pen/GRwKQzj

please check

Comment: I found the solution, now it works thanks